# Como realizar em python um sorteio seguindo uma certa distribuição, como por exemplo distribuições gaussiana ou maxwell-boltzmann?

Tags: python, random

Meu problema é sortear valores de velocidade para uma molécula de hidrogênio segundo uma distribuição de Maxwell-Boltzmann que irá colidir com um elétron (com energia bem definida) e irá se separar em dois fragmentos (2 átomos de hidrogênio). Queria ter uma noção de como sortear valores de velocidade para essa minha molécula inicial segundo a distribuição Maxwell-Boltzmann, entrando com valores de massa da molécula, temperatura e distância de onde ocorreu a colisão para o detector.

Comment: Vc quer usar um variável aleatória continua de Maxwell?

Comment: Na [documentação do módulo `random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#real-valued-distributions) tem uma sessão específica sobre distribuição onde a distribuição de Gauss está incluída. Dê uma olhada lá, quem sabe te ajude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O modulo scipy tem a distribuição Maxwell-Boltzmann integrada, o modulo random só tem o método de Gauss. O modulo scipy é melhor e com maior capacidade em estatística e lhe dará a função de densidade de probabilidade mais fácil de usar!

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.maxwell.html#scipy.stats.maxwell